# LINQ-to-Objects with user queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I am developing / maintaining a tool that allows users to run queries against legacy data files with fixed-width records. The files get converted to a table-like structure using a custom XML specification.

I'm looking for a free/open-source tool that would automatically convert SQL-like queries to LINQ.

FLEE (http://flee.codeplex.com/) can parse simple expressions typed by the user and convert them to .NET code. While it can do the trick for values within a record, it cannot process queries with aggregates, "group by" clauses or other common constructs.

I know I could embed a C# compiler... But I'm looking for something more user-friendly that can be used by a non-programmer with a basic knowledge of SQL.

This tool is only used for analysis and troubleshooting. It doesn't need to run as fast as a real SQL database.

Comment: if the user knows some sql, could you just let them use sql for querying?  not sure of the relative size of the data or if it would be worth it.

Comment: I'm querying a flat file, not an SQL data source. This would only work if there was an SQL-to-anything abstraction layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what syntax you want to support, but in terms of having users put in query bits as strings and converting them into LINQ, there's a couple of existing options out there:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx